# Mapping CRUD Stored Procedures in Entity Framework without edmx editor

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is it possible to map CRUD SPs without using the stupid edmx editor.

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky me.

There is an alpha version of EF6 which supports that. I will try it and if it doesn't work will come back here. If not you will know it is working :)

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping